# How to dynamically set credentials when calling a REST web service with code in Infopath

Tags: infopath, web-services, rest, claims-based-auth

Our SharePoint is configured to use Claims Based Authentication. We want authenticated users in SharePoint to fill a form and some fields will be automatically filled with their personal data. We fetch this data by calling a REST web service and all authenticated users on SharePoint must be authenticated by IIS to call the web service. We cannot pass the username as a web service parameter because information retrieved is sensible information (protected A).

**Problem** :

SharePoint claims based authentication identity are different from windows authentication identity and must be converted, otherwise, users get an Access Denied error (401). As you already know, I can't use SecureStoreService or explicit credentials in an UDCX file because, as a requirement, we don't want to use a service account to call web services. I want to convert Claims Based Authentication identity to classic Windows Authentication identity so that my SharePoint authenticated users will make authenticated calls to my REST web service.

So basically, what I am trying to do is (in pseudo-code) :

1. Get Claims Based Authentication username
2. Convert Username to Windows Authentication username
3. Replace username and set it somehow/somewhere
4. Call web service

Anyone knows how to do that ?